# How can I train this multiclass RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

I am trying to train the following RNN in tensorflow. It takes an 11-D numeric vector as input and it outputs a sequence of 10 multiclass probability vectors, with 14 exclusive classes.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(30, return_sequences=False, input_shape=[1, 11]),
    keras.layers.RepeatVector(10),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(30, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(14, return_sequences=True, activation="softmax")
    ])
    
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam")

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32,
                    validation_split=0.2)
```

However, even for a small dataset of 10 points, it takes hundreds of epochs to fit. As you can see in the figure, the loss barely goes down with the training epochs:

[image]

When I try to train the real training set, the loss simply does not move. Any idea of how to successfully train this model?

You can find the first 10 datapoints [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aVaKtkw-gwSQBE2-SnUjuc4_dGA2eeKh/view?usp=sharing)

And the first 100 datapoints [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aI0daBaZN4-tUEIVrLhrkp0vmC25QVbr/view?usp=sharing)

To load the data just use:

```
with open('train10.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    X_train, y_train = pickle.load(f)
```

Thank you very much for your help

---

EDIT:

To provide additional context, what I have in this problem is a continuous numeric embedding in 11-D to start with, and the output is a sequence of one-hot encodings, so you can think of this problem as training a decoder or doing a decompression to get a sort of "words" back from points in the numeric space (each one-hot vector in the output could be thought of a "letter"). I previously tried to train a non-recurrent network outputting the full list of one-hot encodings (whole "word") at once, but the performance was also very poor. I just do not see what the bottleneck is: if the dimensionality of the numeric embedding, the training algorithm, etc. My tinkering so far with types of layers, numbers of layers, or learning rates did not produce substantial improvements. I am open to sharing the whole dataset if you think that can help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Each machine learning problem is unique and it is very difficult to say exactly what the issue is without having access to the full data set. Some possibilities are:

1. The model specification is suboptimal - try varying the number of hidden layers, the number of neurons in each layer, using GRU/LSTM layers instead of RNN, adding add some dropout layers, etc.
2. The training algorithm needs to be adjusted - try using a different optimizer, a different batch size, a different train-test split ratio etc.
3. The input data needs more (or less) preprocessing - try normalizing/standardizing the input features if you haven't already.
4. You need to do more work on feature engineering - think deeply about all potential relationships between the input data and the target, and try combining columns to create ratios etc. While the NN can theoretically figure this out for itself, it is often effective to try and reduce the work it has to do in this respect.
5. Your problem may just be difficult or even unsolvable. There may just be no strong relationship between the input and the target.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful response tofd. I had a prettly long comment that may help think about this, so I added it to the question. I'd appreciate any further help you can provide.

Comment: Your specified input shape (1,11) suggests you are try to predict an output of shape (10,14) with a single timestep of a input vector with 11 feature columns, which is a strange use of an RNN model (usually takes multiple timesteps as input).

Comment: Thank you very much tofd. I believe this application of RNNs is called "vector-to-sequence". It may have been used in things like image caption generation, where you keep inputting the same image to the network while predicting the sequence.